# Support for multiple user types by Passport-local mongoose node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I wanted two types of users logging in (User, Client). How exactly can I create localStrategies, serialize and deserialize user for both types in my app.js
I have two separate schemas, both using the PassportLocalMongoose plugin.

I currently configuraing my passport like below,

```
var User = require('./models/User');
var Client= require('./models/Client');
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate(), Client.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser(), Client.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser(), Client.deserializeUser());
```

The problem lies when I try to register. Registering as a User works, but as a client shows "Unauthorized" error.
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

After going through the documentation of passport.js (kudos to Jared), I understood that I was doing almost everything wrong.

1. Created two localStrategies

   `passport.use('userLocal', new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
   passport.use('clientLocal', new LocalStrategy(Client.authenticate()));`

and to authenticate,

```
passport.authenticate('userLocal')(req, res, function () {
    res.redirect('/profile');
  });
and
passport.authenticate('clientLocal')(req, res, function () {
    res.redirect('/client');
  });
```

2. Used passport module (l=not using the passport-local-mongoose module) for serializeUser and deseriealizeUser.

   `passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) { 
     done(null, user);
   });`

   `passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
     if(user!=null)
       done(null,user);
   });`

The whole user schema (object) is now stored in the request and can be accessed through any of your routes.

Hope it helps out others with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can make role in mongoose schema and give it to user or client. Based on the role you can do the authentication

Answer (score 0):

you need to create two strategy and edit your serialize and deserialize function for support multiple formats
When you call authenticate() you can specify startegy name

for example 
In middleware

```
exports.authenticateUserA = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('authenticateA', req.body.hostname)
    passport.authenticate('loginA', {failureRedirect: '/login-fail',successRedirect: "/home"}, function (err, player, info) {}})
```

In passport-config.js

```
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
     console.log('deserialize user ')
     if (typeof user.mac_address == 'undefined') {

      user.data_type = 'userTypeA'
      done(null, user);
     } else{
        user.data_type = 'userTypeB'
        done(null, user);
    }

    });
```