# how to apply authentication for different types of users with passport.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using passport.js in my app for authentication(local). I have two types of user - **User** and **Admin**. Both has passport-local-mongoose plugged in. Authentication for **User** was working fine. Then I applied the same authentication process to **Admin**.

It doesn't work neither the **User** which was working fine just before adding auth code to **Admin**. Instead of redirecting to Admin dashboard, it shows **Unauthorized** on the way of registering **Admin**.

I've found a exactly similar problem like mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48831211/support-for-multiple-user-types-by-passport-local-mongoose-node-js/48832614#48832614). I tried the solution given there but it gets worse. My whole app get crashed and shows some `strategy.authenticate is not a function` error.

So, Why this error is showing and how can I  authenticate, serialize and deserialize both **Admin** and **User** in same app?

This is what I've done so far.

#### here is my app.js

```
const passport = require("passport"),
      localStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

const User = require("./models/user"),
      Admin = require("./models/admin");

passport.use(require("express-session") ({ 
    secret : "Wubba lubba dub dub",
    saveUninitialized : false,
    resave : false
}));
app.use(flash());

app.use(passport.initialize()); 
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use("user", new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.use("admin", new localStrategy(Admin.authenticate()));

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => { 
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  if(user!=null)
    done(null,user);
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.currentUser = req.user;
  res.locals.error         = req.flash("error");
  res.locals.success       = req.flash("success");
  next();
});
```

#### user.js login, logout and sign up routes

```
router.get("/userLogin", (req, res) => {
   res.render("user/userLogin");
});

router.post("/userLogin", passport.authenticate("user", {
        successRedirect : "/user/1",
        failureRedirect : "/userLogin",
    }), (req, res)=> {
});

//user sign up handler
router.get("/signUp", (req, res) => {
   res.render("user/userSignup");
});

router.post("/signUp", (req, res) => {
   const newUser = new User({
      firstName : req.body.firstName,
      lastName : req.body.lastName,
      username : req.body.username,
      email : req.body.email,
      gender : req.body.gender,
      address : req.body.address,
   });
   User.register(newUser, req.body.password, (err, user) =>{
      if(err) {
         return res.render("user/userSignup");
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, ()=> {
         res.redirect("/user/1");
      });
   });
});
```

#### admin.js login, logout and signup routes

```
/admin login handler
router.get("/adminLogin", (req, res) => {
   res.render("admin/adminLogin");
});

router.post("/adminLogin", passport.authenticate("admin", {
        successRedirect : "/admin",
        failureRedirect : "/adminLogin",
    }), (req, res)=> {
});

//admin logout handler
router.get("/adminLogout", (req, res) => {
   res.redirect("/");
});

// sign up
router.get("/adminSignup", (req, res) => {
   res.render("signup");
});

router.post("/adminSignup", (req, res) => {
   const newAdmin = new Admin({
      username : req.body.username,
      email : req.body.email,
   });
   Admin.register(newAdmin, req.body.password, (err, user) =>{
      if(err) {
         return res.render("signup");
      }
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {

         res.redirect("/admin");
      });
   });
});
```

#### and isLoggedIn middleware

```
middleware.isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    }
    req.flash("error", "You need to be logged in first");
    res.redirect("/");
};
```